# Forming a variable for a graph using result of searching with awk

Tags: awk, gnu

I´m using cacti to graph CPU usage of equipment with 7 modules, the command used shows 12 samples for each module. I need to use awk to find the pattern of each module name and after form a variable with this sintaxis [module]:[12th CPU sample], for example: MSCBC05:47

Below a extract of command output mentioned:

```
ACT                               AD-46   TIME 141216 1556  MSCBC05
PROCESSOR LOAD DATA
INT PLOAD CALIM OFFDO OFFDI FTCHDO FTCHDI OFFMPH OFFMPL FTCHMPH FTCHMPL
 1   46   56250   656    30   656     30   1517      2   1517       2
 2   47   56250   659    32   659     32   1448      1   1448       1
 3   46   56250   652    22   652     22   1466      1   1466       1
 4   47   56250   672    33   672     33   1401      0   1401       0
 5   47   56250   674    38   674     38   1446      2   1446       2
 6   45   56250   669    22   669     22   1365      1   1365       1
 7   45   56250   674    26   674     26   1394      2   1394       2
 8   46   56250   664    24   664     24   1396      0   1396       0
 9   47   56250   686    24   686     24   1425      2   1425       2
10   47   56250   676    31   676     31   1386      0   1386       0
11   48   56250   702    25   702     25   1414      2   1414       2
12   47   56250   703    31   703     31   1439      2   1439       2
```

Complete output
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/33222611/raw_output.txt

Comment: Post sample input, expected output, a MUCH better description just in terms of fields in rows and columns (forget all this "catci" stuff and if you're going to talk about "modules" then tell us where "modules" show up in rows/columns with examples from your input) and how they are mapped from input to output and an example of what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest

```
awk '$1 == "ACT" { sub(/\r/, ""); curmsc = $6 } curmsc != "" && $1 == "12" { print curmsc ":" $2; curmsc = "" }' raw_output.txt
```

Written more readably, that is

```
$1 == "ACT" {    # In the first line of an ACT block
  sub(/\r/, "")  # remove the trailing carriage return. Could also use todos or so.
  curmsc = $6    # remember MSC
}
curmsc != "" && $1 == "12" {  # if we are in such a block and the first token is 12
  print curmsc ":" $2         # print the stuff we want to know
  curmsc = ""                 # then flag that we're outside a block
}
```

Comment: Wintermute, thanks for your help. Your suggestion works perfectly. (https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/33222611/module_graph.JPG)